# Perl: Array of hashes - Get the element with id in hash

Tags: perl

I have a Perl data structure, loaded from a json, with `Data::Dumper` looking like this:

```perl
$VAR1 = {
    'Stat' => [
        {
            'statCfgFile' => 'statcfg_0001.json',
            'statid' => 1,
            'status' => 'running',
            'something' => 'other'
        },
        {
            'statCfgFile' => 'statcfg_0002.json',
            'statid' => 2,
            'status' => 'running'
            'something' => 'other'
        }
    ]
}
```

From another dataset, I get a statid to read the hash, but the given id does not match the array key, therefore I need to go into deep, reading the `statid` property.

Of course, I could loop through the array, but with a large array list, that might hit performance.

Is there a way to directly access the array element by the `statid` stored in the hash?

As the data model is in my hands and currently in development:
Would it be better not to use an array, but also a hash with the `statid` as the naming element?

Comment: How often do you have to look things up by `statid` in the same structure? If it's just once, a linear scan is pretty much optimal. If it's more than once, it can be more efficient to convert the whole thing to a hash (keyed by `statid`) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't pull a value out of an array based on a criteria without iterating over the array. But there are ways to write it without using a loop.

Say the data structure is `$data` and you want to pull hashes where `statid` equals `$id_to_find`.

```
my @matching_hashes = grep {$_->{statid} = $id_to_find}} @{$data->{Stat}};
```

If only the first hash matching the ID is relevant, you could use the core module `List::Util` function `first`, which does the same thing as `grep` but only returns the first match instead of a list. It would be faster than `grep` because it stops iterating over the array as soon as it finds one match.

```
use List::Util 'first';
my $matching hash = first {$_->{statid} = $id_to_find}} @{$data->{Stat}};
```

As you indicated, using hash lookups is much faster than list operations. You could create a hash index of array adresses. Note this still requires you iterate over the array once.

```
# create the index;
my %index;
my @array = @{$data->{Stat}};
for my $address (0..$#array) {     # "$#array" is the last element of @array
    my $hash = $array[$address];
    my $id = $hash->{statid};
    $index{$id} = $address;        # now you can use an ID to get the array address
}

# use the index
my $id_to_find = 42;
my $wanted_array_address = $index{$id_to_find};
my $matching_hash = $data->{Stat}->[$wanted_array_address];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `statid` field is unique then I suggest you use something more like this

```
{
    1 => 'statcfg_0001.json',
    2 => 'statcfg_0002.json',
}
```

> The hash includes more data than shown. I extend the example

Then you need a hash instead of just a string value for each `statid`

```
{
    1 => {
        statCfgFile => 'statcfg_0001.json',
        statid      => 1,
        status      => 'running',
        something   => 'other',
    },
    2 => {
        statCfgFile => 'statcfg_0002.json',
        statid      => 2,
        status      => 'running',
        something   => 'other',
    },
}
```

Comment: The hash includes more data than shown. I extend the example.

Comment: I will update my data structure to have a hash instead on an array. Thank you for your answer.